# Advices for filesystem choice and tuning on SSD?

Tags: performance, filesystems, ssd

What is your favourite filesystem on [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) disks, and why?

I'm asking because on my [Acer Aspire One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire_One) with 8 GB SSD with [ReiserFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS) it takes ages to boot after an unclean shutdown, so I'm probably missing something. I thought ReiserFS woud be a good choice, but it probably isn't.

And also:
Once a filesystem has been chosen, What options are suited for this kind of disks? I heard something about aligning filesystem blocks with SSD cells (I hope those terms are appropriate), but how do I actually find the right block size?

Answer (score 3):

The cell size I've typically seen on SSDs is 64 kbytes, but it tends to get more complicated that that. I've found [an interesting-looking article](http://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/02/20/aligning-filesystems-to-an-ssds-erase-block-size/) that I haven't studied in-depth, but which looks to have a reasonably detailed investigation into such things.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to wait for 2.6.30 and you're okay with trying a newcomer, [NILFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS) is set for inclusion into the 2.6.30 mainline tree.

http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7345/1.html

The benchmarks look great and it apparently addresses the exact issue you've been seeing.

Comment: Follow Up: 2.6.30 has been released :)